# ExecutorService.execute() does not return the thread type

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have something like this

```
public static void runThread(Thread t){
    ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    threadExecutor.execute(t);
}
```

if I do `Thread.currentThread()`, then I get back `weblogic.work.ExecuteThread` or sometimes `java.lang.Thread` (I used Weblogic as my AppServer), but if I do

```
public static void runThread(Thread t){
    //ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    //threadExecutor.execute(t);
    t.start();
}
```

then when I dod `Thread.currentThread()`, I get back `com.my.thread.JSFExecutionThread`, which is the Thread that I passed in and this is what I want. Is there a way to fix so the `ExecutorService#execute()` return the correct Thread type like `Thread#start()`? The thing is that I want to use ExecutorService, because I want to leverage `shutdown()` and `shutdownNow()`

**EDIT**

Is there anything wrong with this implementation?

```
/**
 * Run {@code Runnable runnable} with {@code ExecutorService}
 * @param runnable {@code Runnable}
 * @return 
 */
public static ExecutorService runThread(Thread t){
    ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(
            new ExecutionThreadFactory(t));
    threadExecutor.execute(t);
    return threadExecutor;
}

private static class ExecutionThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory{
    private JSFExecutionThread jsfThread;
    ExecutionThreadFactory(Thread t){
        if(t instanceof JSFExecutionThread){
            jsfThread = (JSFExecutionThread)t;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        if(jsfThread != null){
            return jsfThread;
        }else{
            return new Thread(r);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, since if you use `ExecutorService.execute(t)`, it executes on the `ExecutorService`'s thread, not `t` itself. Note that `ExecutorService.execute` accepts `Runnable`, not only `Thread`.

Comment: @johnchen902: Not even with the help of `ThreadFactory`?

Comment: @ThangPham I'm not sure. But I'll change my design if I run into this.

Comment: @BheshGurung: well, Thread implements Runnable, so I think it should be fine here.

Comment: @johnchen902: I update my question, can u take a look at my updated code, please?

Comment: Why don't you try it? However if `shutdown()` and `shutdownNow()` works, `Thread.interrupt()` works, too. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow()): *"There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate."*

Comment: @johnchen902: With interrupt(), I have to check isInterrupt() in the run method, right? Do I have to do that for shutdown() and shutdownNow()?

Comment: @ThangPham Yes and no. To use `shutdownNow` and have it terminate immediately you would need to check the interrupt status of the `Thread`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anything wrong with this implementation?

Yes.

First, the `ExecutorService` manages the lifetime of each `Thread` from the time the `ThreadFactory` creates it until the executor is done with it... and the punchline, a `Thread` is not re-usable, once it has terminated it can not be started.

Second

```
public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
    if(jsfThread != null){
        return jsfThread;
    }else{
        return new Thread(r);
    }
}
```

This code violates the contract of `ThreadFactory.newThread` by not making the `Runnable` `r` set as the runnable to be executed by the `jsfThread`.